# Error Creating New VMs using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I'm struggling to create a new virtual machine on Hyper-V using a simple example from the help file. I can create VMs manually using the GUI but I was trying to learn how to do this using PowerShell but I'm getting the error below.

```
New-VM -Name "base" -MemoryStartupBytes 1GB -NewVHDPath "J:\Hyper-V machines\dc.vhdx" -NewVHDSizeBytes 100GB
```

Error Message:

```
New-VM : Failed to create a new virtual machine. 'base' failed to realize.
(Virtual machine ID  80967A7D-7380-4771-B200-99129D63496C) Failed to access
configuration store: The device is not ready. (0x80070015).
At line:1 char:1
+ New-VM -Name "base" -MemoryStartupBytes 1GB -NewVHDPath J:\VM\base.vh ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-VM], VirtualizationExcept     ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unspecified,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.NewVM
```

My VMs are located in an external harddrive and the path exists ...there's not much help about this error online.

Comment: Are you trying to use an existing VM, and that VM is located at: "J:\Hyper-V machines\dc.vhdx" ?
From the help, -NewVHDPath <String>
        Creates a new virtual hard disk with the specified path and connects it to the new virtual machine. Absolute paths are allowed. If only a file name is specified, the virtual hard disk is created in the default path configured for the host.
Have you tried -vhdpath? That will use an existing VHD. Thanks, Tim.

Comment: i finally found a walk around, not sure why it worked this time. i guess the only difference is that i added more parameters(-Generation, and -Path ) and chose certain combinations.

i tried a couple of combinations untill i finally got one that worked

-BootDevice = CD and Generation = 2 (didn't work)
-BootDevice = VHD and Generation = 2 (worked)
-BootDevice = CD and Generation = 1 (worked)       . Not sure how i can add the working code don't see any options for adding code without exceeding the character limit